# multiple conditions select nodes powershell version 2 XLST 1

Tags: xml, powershell, xslt-1.0

```
<nodes>
  <node> 
   <nodeFullName>JohnSmith</nodefullname>
   <nodeName>John</nodeName>
  </node>
  <node>
     <nodeFullName>JohnSecond</nodefullname>
    <nodeName>John</nodeName>
  </node>
</nodes>
```

I want to return the node that matches a given name and last name (case insensitive)

```
          $XMLFILE.SelectNodes("//nodes/node[translate(nodeName,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')=""$Name"" and  starts-with(nodeFullName,concat($Name,$LastName) ]")
```

however both nodes are returned, the second condition (after and) is not checked , what am i missing?

Comment: `-and` instead of and?

Comment: no this is XSLT 1.0 notation , not powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not close your Start-With function before you close the filter, you only close the concact. The end of that line should read:

```
$Name,$LastName))]")
```

Instead of:

```
$Name,$LastName)]")
```

It may be simpler to join the first and last name in PowerShell beforehand instead of using concact though, imho.

```
$FullName = $Name.tolower() + $LastName.tolower()
```

Then your starts-with can read:

```
starts-with(translate(nodeFullName,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),""$FullName"")]")
```

Here is the full code that I tested with:

```
$XMLFILE = [XML]@"
<nodes>
  <node> 
   <nodeFullName>JohnSmith</nodeFullName>
   <nodeName>John</nodeName>
  </node>
  <node>
     <nodeFullName>JohnSecond</nodeFullName>
    <nodeName>John</nodeName>
  </node>
</nodes>
"@
$Name = "John"
$LastName = "SMITH"
$FirstName = $Name.ToLower()
$FullName = $Fname + $LastName.ToLower()
$XMLFILE.SelectNodes("//nodes/node[translate(nodeName,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')=""$FName"" and starts-with(translate(nodeFullName,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),""$FullName"")]")
```

That resulted in:

```
nodeFullName        nodeName
------------        --------
JohnSmith           John
```